# Looking for short story involving pruning away alternate universes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m looking for a short story in which humanity discover that alternate universes exist, but every few years all of the alternates are destroyed except for one which becomes the main branch.  The surviving branch is most likely to involve war.  The protagonists become paralyzed with indecision because any decision could mean survival at the expense of annihilation of countless billions.

The different realities were referred to by letters (a,b…etc) and the powerful authority was referred to as an arrogant idiot.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Ryan, welcome to Sci-Fi & Fantasy! Please read [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and add as much additional information as you can.